# Laravel web root path - where is it

Tags: laravel, web, root

I installed laravel at /var/www/laravel on Ubuntu

Can you please tell me how to access the laravel framework from browser ?

Comment: You have to setup a webserver, e.g. apache. Or use nginx together with PHP. See e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/var/www/laravel` directory and run the command `php artisan serve`

The `artisan` command is just a command-line utility for Laravel.  The serve command just starts up the PHP server, which you can do yourself as well with PHP -S 8080 (which would start a PHP web server (single-threaded) in the current directory on port 8080)

If you want to define the host ip then use below command to set host and port

```
php artisan serve --host=<host IP address> --port=<port to use>

php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8080
```

If you want to access a simple way without serve command.

> server_ip/projectname/public

you'll see the your home page there,